# Sorting an index through an associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index that displays all of the current "dprojects" created. I'm working on being able to click the table headers to sort the data by that parameter. I have this all working except for one column. This column displays our customers by the number we've assigned them. For example, "Customer A" is "008". The "dprojects" table has a column for customer ID, and the "schools" table has columns for both the ID and the actual name of the customer.

Because it is a "dprojects" index, the table is sorting by the ID associated with the customer, and not the customer's name. How can I get it to sort alphabetically by name? Here's my code:

view: (dname is the customer name within the school model)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <th> <%= sortable "scode", "School" %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @dprojects.where.not(status: "Completed").each do |dproject| %>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" class="dotted"><%= dproject.school.dname[0,25] + "..." %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

model:

```
class Dproject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school, foreign_key: 'scode'
end
```

controller:

```
def index
    @dprojects = Dproject.order(params[:sort])
    respond_with(@dprojects)
end
```

helper:

```
module DprojectsHelper
    def sortable(column, title = nil)
        title ||= column.titleize
        link_to title, :sort => column
    end
end
```

I thought I would be able to modify the view with the line:

```
<th> <%= sortable "dproject.school.dname", "School" %></th>
```

but that doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is because there is no such column (`dproject.school.dname`) in `@dprojects`. You need to join the tables in order to access also the columns of the model `School`.

I was tested the sorting on a model `Book` `Author`, where `Book` `belongs_to :author`, pretty similar to your. For the sorting to work I did like what follows:

In controller there is a join table, note the aliases (AS):

```
sort_by =  params[:sort] || 'author_name'
    @books = Book.joins(:author).select('books.name AS book_name, authors.name AS author_name').order(sort_by)
```

I used `sort_by` to avoid ambiguous column `name`, as for me there is name column in both models.

Then in view:

```
<p>id | <%= sortable 'book_name', 'Book' %> | <%= sortable 'author_name', 'Author' %></p>
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <p><%= book.book_name %> | <%= book.author_name %> </p>
<% end %>
```